# Techniques to reduce data duplication in a people database

Tags: python, database, mongodb, duplicates

we will be building a people database for a specific industry.  The info will come from lots of different sources (mostly web scraping and public DBs).

Not every single source will have a usable unique id (such as a tax id), so we are looking for ways to reduce duplicate data.

We were thinking in hashing the person's email and name and using that as a kind of unique key.

Any methods/suggestions that will help us reduce duplicates will be appreciated.

We'll be using MongoDb and many different python scripts if that is useful.

Cheers!

Comment: Hashing can still produce duplicate values, so won't technically work as a unique keys.

Comment: What attributes will each instance have? height, weight, gender, email etc?

Comment: @rangeseeker it will vary, it will almost always have name and contact info.  We'll basically put everything we find in each data sources into do mongo document, so the amount of info we get will vary between the records.

Comment: Initially I though of using the email as a unique field.  However, in more than one occasion two or more people share have the same email on record.

Comment: Typical EMPIs (Entreprise Master Patient/Person Index) use combinations of attributes to determine if two records describe the same person.  Each matching field has a weight (sometimes a factor of edit distance) and a minimum number of common fields is defined as a threshold for automatic pairing.  You might want to look into how these tools perform their magic.

Comment: Thank you @AlainT.  

I've been looking into it and I think that will be as good as it gets.